# Making a legend / getting handles of Kaplan Meier plot objects in python lifelines

Tags: python, matplotlib, legend, lifelines

I'm working with the [lifelines package](https://lifelines.readthedocs.io/en/latest/fitters/univariate/KaplanMeierFitter.html) to make Kaplan-Meier curves. I'd like to add the censored data, but also have a legend that only mentions the two lines.

I'm calling the function iteratively twice to plot two separate lines, as so:

```
def plot_km(col,months,dpi):
  ax = plt.subplot(111)
  clrIdx = 0
  for r in df[col].unique():
    ix = df[col] == r
    plt.rcParams['figure.dpi'] = dpi
    plt.rcParams['savefig.dpi'] = dpi
    kmf.fit(T[ix], C[ix],label=r)
    kmf.plot(ax=ax, color=colorsKM[clrIdx],show_censors=True,censor_styles={'ms': 6, 'marker': 's','label':'_out_'})
    if clrIdx == 1:
        plt.legend(handles=[],labels=['test1', 'test2'])
    clrIdx += 1
```

Where the output is a KM curve as well as the censored datapoints. However, I can't seem to figure out a way to interact with the handles/labels that gets the desired output. The above code seems to ignore the censored objects by using `'label':'_out_'` , but it ignores my custom labels in the `plt.legend()` call. If I enter anything for handles, e.g.: `plt.legend(handles=[line0]` , it throws "NameError: name 'line0' is not defined"

[image]

I tried playing around with `h, l = ax.get_legend_handles_labels()` but this always returns empty. I believe my issue is with not understanding how each of these "artists"(?) are getting stored, and how to get them again.

Comment: Without a more complete code and test data, it is hard to guess what you are doing. Anyway, `plt.legend(handles=[], ...)` isn't supposed to draw anything.  Handles can either be existing graphical elements of a plot, or dummy elements that got created without adding them to the plot.  You can either assign a label or provide these labels in the call to `plt.legend()`. By default, all elements in the plot that got a label (not staring with `'_'`) will be used as handles.  As `plt.legend()` removes a possible previously existing legend, the clearest way would be to call it after the `for` loop.

Comment: Thank you @JohanC ! I was overthinking it somewhat. As you pointed out, getting rid of the plt.legend(handles=...) caused the legend to default to what I had named it in the plot call :) As you guessed, my confusion was with the utility of plt.legend()